# IndexError: list index out of range discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, discord-api

Пишу бота для дискорд и сделал функцию, скидывающую пикчу по тегам с сайта

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def yandere(ctx):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
        try:
            async with cs.get('https://yande.re/post.json?limit=101&tags={}'.format(ctx.message.content).replace('im!yandere ', '')) as r:
                res = await r.json()
                await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, res[random.randrange(-1, -100, -1)]['file_url'])
        except TypeError:
            async with cs.get('https://yande.re/post.json?limit=101&tags=') as r:
                res = await r.json()
                await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, res[random.randrange(-1, -100, -1)]['file_url'])
```

В чем может быть ошибка? Потому что команда gelbooru работает по тому же принципу что и эта

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\discord_bot\main.py", line 178, in yandere
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, res[random.randrange(-1, -100, -1)]['file_url'])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: В `res` нет данных по индексу выдаваемому `random.randrange(-1, -100, -1)`

Comment: Спасибо, исправил путем замены TypeError на IndexError

Comment: в вашем случае, вместо try/except, постарайтесь понять причину ошибки и устранить её.